# AJAX call sometimes produces error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone explain to me why my ajax call works the initial time on the page and continues to work until i have been on the page for a while without any action.   It seems as if it is timing out but that cannot be possible because its retrieving values from input boxes and making the ajax calls with those values.

```
        $('#cmdSubmit_Search').click(function () {
        $('#hdnMode').val('search');
        $('#divResults').hide();
        $('#divLoading').fadeIn(250);

        var searchParam = $('#ddSearchBy_Search').val();
        var searchValue;
        if ($('#ddSearchBy_Search').val() == "schoolid") {
            searchValue = $('#ddSearchSchools').val();
        }
        else {
            searchValue = $('#txtSearchValue').val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SourceCodeTool.aspx/searchSources",
            data: '{"searchParam":"' + searchParam + '","searchValue":"' + searchValue + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                $('#divLoading').hide();
                $('#divResults').fadeIn(2000);
                document.getElementById('divResults').innerHTML = msg.d;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $('#divLoading').fadeOut(500);
                alert('error' + error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: What errors do you actually get?

Comment: i simply get undefined.  It makes no sense at to why it would work sometimes and other times it does not.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because sometimes the variable msg on the success callback returns undefined. You are not checking for null, empty, or undefined for that variable.